# 'Auto Draft' Post showing in wordpress loop

Tags: loop, draft

When running a wordpress loop, I am seeing these weird posts called auto draft.  I have never seen this before.  Does anyone know what they are and how to get rid of them?

Any help is appreciated as I am lost on this one.

[image]

THe loop I used is:

```
<div class="archive-steps-to-hs">
   <div class="container">
      <div class="row">

         <?php // WP_Query arguments
         $args = array (
            'post_type'       => 'step_to_hs',
            'post_status'     => 'published',
            );

            // The Query
         $query = new WP_Query( $args );

            // The Loop
         if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
            while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
               $query->the_post(); ?>
                  <div class="panel panel-default">
                     <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                           <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#<?php the_id(); ?>">
                              <?php the_title(); ?>
                           </a>
                        </h4>
                     </div>
                     <div id="<?php the_id(); ?>" class="panel-collapse collapse collapse.in">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                           <?php the_content(); ?>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               <?php }
            } else {
               echo 'Sorry - there are no steps to display right now';
            }

            // Restore original Post Data
            wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

      </div>
   </div>
</div><!-- archive-steps-to-hs -->
```

I am using the bootstrap collapse javascript to style the loop.  I have tried just doing a regular loop without the jQuery and styling, but same thing still shows.

Comment: What is your code for the loop there? Auto drafts are created when you start on a post, but hadn't saved it yet.

Comment: Try disabling all plugins. If the behaviour goes away, re-enable them one by one till it resumes -- that'll be your culprit. If it's not a plugin, then it could be your theme -- does the behaviour show up in a default theme like Twenty Fourteen?  If not, it's something in your theme.

Comment: Make sure you aren't using `'post_status' => 'any'`. Also, double check your list of published posts to make sure there aren't any published items with that (default) post title.

Comment: As already suggested, there is something wrong with your Loop code. Please [edit] that code into the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change `published` to `publish`.

```
$args = array (
    'post_type'       => 'step_to_hs',
    'post_status'     => 'publish',
);

// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

#### Reference

- [WP_Query status parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Status_Parameters)

Comment: Goofy little typos are often the *hardest* things to debug. Glad it works for you.